# Best way to merge a 2d list and a 1d list in Python?

Tags: python, list, merge

I need to merge a two dimensional list and a single dimensional list without losing elements.

I used a loop to achieve the result but I'd like to know if there is a better way.

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
list2 = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8"]]
max_column_count = len(list1)
expected_result = [list1]
for row in list2:
    if max_column_count > len(row):
        columns = max_column_count - len(row)
        row += [''] * columns
    expected_result.append(row)
print(expected_result)
```

output

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['1', '2', '3', ''], ['4', '5', '6', ''], ['7', '8', '', '']]
```

Comment: Is that your expected output?...if not. post it

Comment: Please specify expected input and output?

Comment: The code above is already doing the job, so the output is the output and the expected output. My question was if there was a better/best way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you post as output is your expected output, then using [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.chain) from `itertools` will be one way to go:

```
>>> mx_len = len(max([list1,*list2]))
>>> 
>>> mx_len
4
>>> [x+['']*(mx_len-len(x)) for x in itertools.chain([list1], list2)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['1', '2', '3', ''], ['4', '5', '6', ''], ['7', '8', '', '']]
>>>
>>> #another way by unpacking list2 in a list with list1
>>>
>>> [x+['']*(mx_len-len(x)) for x in itertools.chain([list1, *list2])]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['1', '2', '3', ''], ['4', '5', '6', ''], ['7', '8', '', '']]
```

Another way would be a *double zipping* effect, like transposing both lists using [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.zip_longest) and fill the missing values with `''` then zipping again the lists to get back to the original shape, this way:

```
>>> l1 = itertools.zip_longest(list1, *list2, fillvalue='')
>>> 
>>> l2 = list(zip(*l1))
>>>
>>> l2
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('1', '2', '3', ''), ('4', '5', '6', ''), ('7', '8', '', '')]
```

Comment: I knew zip_longest would do it but I didn't know how to do with it.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: @SinanÇetinkaya .. sure ..:)

Comment: @IronFist What about perfomance, which perfom faster and efficent?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the resulting list to contain lists of the same size, with padding empty strings:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
list2 = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8"]]
req_len = len(list1)
result = [list1] + [org + [''*(req_len - len(org))] for org in list2]
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
... list2 = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8"]]
... list3 = [list1] + map(lambda x: x + ['']*(len(list1)-len(x)),list2)
>>> list3
6: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 ['1', '2', '3', ''],
 ['4', '5', '6', ''],
 ['7', '8', '', '']]
>>>
```

This is essentially the same as what you're doing, but more terse. If you don't know about the map function, this is a good time to learn (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
list2 = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8"]]
list3 = []
list3.append(list1)
list3.append(list2)
>>>
list3 =[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8']]]
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would make your contribution more valuable and also conform to the StackOverflow guidelines for posting Answers (see the Help Center)...